# uk time zone format for the day light saving

Tags: java

I am using GMT+1 for uk time zone in my code. My problem is for daylight saving it will not work. Can i use BST in place of that so that it will automatically take care of the daylight saving.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you should use the time zone identifier of "Europe/London" as that is the time zone observed by the UK. It should then be accurate for both standard time and daylight saving time.

(As a general note, if you're doing any significant date and time work in Java, it's worth checking out [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) - a *much* nicer API than the built-in one.)

Comment: what is the problem using BST. Can you please explain so that i ll get a clear idea. thank you

Comment: @gusaindpk: BST is British Summer Time - so it's inappropriate for the winter. In modern times, the UK uses UTC+0 in the winter, and UTC+1 in the summer. Those are often called GMT and BST respectively. The Europe/London time zone covers *both*.

Answer (score 2):

assert TimeZone.getTimeZone("BST").getDisplayName().equals("Bangladesh Time");

Comment: yes, you are right  "BST" is not British Summer Time in java, its for Bangladesh Time